# Android + setDividerDrawable on a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, drawable, android-linearlayout

I'm interested in adding dividers to a LinearLayout's children dynamically.  I see in the docs that LinearLayout contains a CONST "SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE" along with get and set divider methods.  Can someone show me how I implement it?  Thanks!

*"This does not work"*

**layout xml:**

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_height="40dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ab_background_gradient" android:gravity="right|center_vertical">

        <!-- sort button -->
        <Button android:id="@+id/sortBtn" android:background="@drawable/defaultt"
                android:layout_width="30dip" android:layout_height="30dip" android:onClick="sortThis" />

        <!-- add button -->
        <Button android:id="@+id/addBtn" android:background="@drawable/defaultt"
                android:layout_width="30dip" android:layout_height="30dip" android:onClick="addThis" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**main:**

```
...
private void setupViews() {
        //bar
        mBar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bar);
        mBar.setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.divider);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to convert the Resource id you get back from `R.drawable.divider` into a *Drawable* object, ala:

```java
import android.content.res.Resources;
...

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    Resources res = this.getResources();

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE | LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_BEGINNING | LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_END);
    layout.setDividerDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.divider));

    ...
 }
...
```

This assumes you've got a file named 'divider.jpg' (or similar) in your resources directory.

Comment: This works, but note that setShowDividers was added in API level 11 (Honeycomb).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304221/nosuchmethod-exception-for-setshowdividers

Comment: @worked you can use IcsLinearLayout that is in ActionBarSherlock if you wish, but do note that it's not intended to be used. there is also LinearLayoutICS which is in the support library

Comment: Xamarin Developers use this _tabLayout.SetDividerDrawable(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.divider));